# Getting SSID of the connected wifi network in Xamarin.iOS, iOS 13

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios13

After passing from iOS 12 to 13 I am no more able to get the SSID of the connected wifi network.

I tried the solution for iOS 13 proposed in
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539526/getting-the-ssid-of-the-connected-wifi-on-ios-12-xamarin-updated-for-ios-13)
but with no result.

My previous successful code for iOS 12 (moreover 'CaptiveNetwork' is deprecated now):

```
if (CaptiveNetwork.TryGetSupportedInterfaces(out string[] supportedInterfaces) == StatusCode.OK)
{
    foreach (var item in supportedInterfaces)
    {
        if (CaptiveNetwork.TryCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(item, out NSDictionary info) == StatusCode.OK)
        {
            var ssid = info[CaptiveNetwork.NetworkInfoKeySSID].ToString();
            return ssid;
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Check if your app has the permission of location in system setting .After iOS 13.0 , app will never return SSID without this permission .

Comment: Ok it works, for the moment :). But an alternative to CaptiveNetwork which is deprecated? The documentation suggests me to use NetworkExtensio.NEHotspotHelper...

Comment: The framework is not currently open for use on a large scale, so you need to send an application to apple and approve it to gain access to the framework. So you need to have a developer account. You  can check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/156955/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-wifi-signals-in-ios

Comment: Ok, let's see if it becomes simpler in the future

Comment: Actually , you can still use it now :)

Comment: Sadly NEHotspotConfigurationManager.SharedManager.GetConfiguredSsidsAsync always returns null... even when im connected to the network that the app connected to. I have to keep using the obsolete way - only thing that works.. sigh

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for iOS 13**: Apple announced that iOS 13, the CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo API will no longer return valid Wi-Fi SSID and BSSID information.

If your app requires valid Wi-Fi SSID and BSSID information to function, you can do the following: · For accessory setup apps, use the NEHotSpotConfiguration API, which now has the option to pass a prefix of the SSID hotspot your app expects to connect to. · For other types of apps, use the CoreLocation API to request the user’s consent to access location information.

So, I updated the above solution in the following way:

Add this key to your info.plist:

```
 <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
 <string>Your Description</string>
```

Use the CoreLocation API to request the user’s consent to access location information.

```
    private void GetLocationConsent()
{
    var manager = new CLLocationManager();
    manager.AuthorizationChanged += (sender, args) => {
        Console.WriteLine("Authorization changed to: {0}", args.Status);
    };
    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
        manager.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization();

}
```

Call the GetLocationConsent() function before calling the "CaptiveNetwork".