# How to get the connected SSID in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, wifi, ssid

I need to get the **SSID** of the current network that I am connected to.

Here is the code I used to find the **SSID in Xamarin.Android**:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)(Application.Context.GetSystemService(WifiService));

if (wifiManager != null)
{
    var ssid =  wifiManager.ConnectionInfo.SSID;
}
else
{
    var str =  "WiFiManager is NULL";
}
```

But I need to implement this in **Xamarin.Forms**.

How can I do this ?

Comment: I'm sorry, on my anwser i said that Dependency(typeof()) was IGetSSID, wich is incorrect, i have updated my anwser, it's Dependency(typeof(GetSSIDAndroid))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction).

> The DependencyService class is a service locator that enables Xamarin.Forms applications to invoke native platform functionality from shared code.

**1º**
Create a public interface (for organization sake, maybe under `Mobile > Services > IGetSSID`)

```
public interface IGetSSID
{
    string GetSSID();
}
```

**2º** Create the Android Implementation

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(GetSSIDAndroid))]
namespace yournamespace
{
    public class GetSSIDAndroid : IGetSSID
    {
        public string GetSSID()
        {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)(Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService));

            if (wifiManager != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(wifiManager.ConnectionInfo.SSID))
            {
                return wifiManager.ConnectionInfo.SSID;
            }
            else
            {
                return "WiFiManager is NULL";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**3º**
Then in your forms you get the SSID like this:

```
var ssid = DependencyService.Get<IGetSSID>().GetSSID();
```

---

Note: Don't forget to add this permission on your Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Any chance you know of a clean way to get this for iOS?

Comment: @David I found this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58542114/getting-ssid-of-the-connected-wifi-network-in-xamarin-ios-ios-13), following the same logic for iOS, i'm sure you can implement it, if needed, i can update my awnser to include it.

Comment: Forgive me for my illiteracy but how do I get access to WifiManager

Comment: It tells me NullReferenceException, on the step 3°

Comment: @BluePrint where are you using the `ssid = DependencyService.Get<IGetSSID>().GetSSID();` part?

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais in the Main Window, there i also created the public interface

Comment: @BluePrint the public interface shouldn't be in the Main Window, it should be in a separated file, preferably in **Mobile > Services > IGetSSID** like i said in the answer but it can be anywhere inside your **Shared Project** if it's easier for you

Answer (score 0):

### Get SSID and BSSID API31 Xamarin C# Example

Required permissions: CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

If API<31 **TransportInfo** will return Null

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Net;
using Android.Net.Wifi;

protected override void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();

        NetworkRequest request = new NetworkRequest.Builder().AddTransportType(transportType: TransportType.Wifi).Build();
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService) as ConnectivityManager;

        NetworkCallbackFlags flagIncludeLocationInfo = NetworkCallbackFlags.IncludeLocationInfo;
        NetworkCallback networkCallback = new NetworkCallback((int)flagIncludeLocationInfo);
        connectivityManager.RequestNetwork(request, networkCallback);
    }

    private class NetworkCallback : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback
    {
        public NetworkCallback(int flags) : base(flags)
        {
        }

        public override void OnCapabilitiesChanged(Network network, NetworkCapabilities networkCapabilities)
        {
            base.OnCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = (WifiInfo)networkCapabilities.TransportInfo;

            if (wifiInfo != null)
            {
                string ssid = wifiInfo.SSID.Trim(new char[] {'"', '\"' });
                string bssid = wifiInfo.BSSID;
            }
        }
    }
```

Click [Android API reference.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback#NetworkCallback(int))!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).