# Xamarin.Essentials: Connectivity Internet Network SSID

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.essentials

Does `Xamarin.Essentials: Connectivity` provide a way to get the SSID i.e Connected internet network name in xamarin forms?

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Essential has the `Connectivity class` and it lets you monitor for changes in the device's network conditions, check the current network access, and how it is currently connected. You can check the [Xamarin.Essentials: Connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?tabs=android) for more information.

In addition, you can check this answer about [How to get the connected SSID in Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60486196/how-to-get-the-connected-ssid-in-xamarin-forms)