# Error getting network SSID in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, captivenetwork

I added this key to Info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your Description</string>
```

And checked "Add access to wifi information" in Entitlements.plist.

I asked the user for permission to Location as well:

```
var manager = new CLLocationManager();
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
    manager.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization();
```

I click "allow", and then I would like to get the wifi information:

```
if (CLLocationManager.Status is CLAuthorizationStatus.Authorized || 
    CLLocationManager.Status is CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways || 
    CLLocationManager.Status is CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse)
{
  if (CaptiveNetwork.TryGetSupportedInterfaces(out string[] supportedInterfaces) == StatusCode.OK)
  {
    foreach (var item in supportedInterfaces)
    {
      if (CaptiveNetwork.TryCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(item, out NSDictionary info) == StatusCode.OK)
      {
        var ssid = info[CaptiveNetwork.NetworkInfoKeySSID].ToString();
        System.Console.WriteLine(ssid);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the info variable is always null.

I would like to get the SSID and the protection level (WPA, WPA2 etc.) of the connected wifi network.

I use iPhone SE iOS 14.4. The software versions:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.8.4
- Xamarin   16.8.000.261
- Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   14.8.0.3 (c51fabee8)
- XCode 12.3

Comment: Have you enable the Access WiFi Information capability for your app?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT In the Entitlements.plist, yes. But do I need to participate in the Apple Developer Program, and enable Access WiFi Information capability at the apple developer portal?

Comment: You could check the link below for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539526/getting-the-ssid-of-the-connected-wifi-on-ios-12-xamarin-updated-for-ios-13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to participate in the Apple Developer Program, and enable Access WiFi Information capability at the apple developer portal.